# spring boot fails to read libraries supplied in classpath in minikube hostpath mounted in more than one instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube

I have a spring boot application which will be added as a side car application in Kubernetes along with all other applications.  This application has some sub modules which can be added through class path only when required. I could achieve this by mounting volume into Kubernetes using host path.

Since, I was using minikube in my local mac pc. I had to first mount my local folder to minikube (using minikube mount /Users/nischal/Documents/kubeApps/app1/:/app1) and then use it in pods in the following way.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-pod-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
        containers:
           - name: app1
             image: app1
             imagePullPolicy: Never
             ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
             volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /app/lib
                  name: app-lib-storage-dep
                  readOnly: true
        volumes:
           - name: app-lib-storage-dep
             hostPath:
                path: /app1/lib
                type: Directory
```

Following is my docker file

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.8-jre-slim as builder
WORKDIR application
COPY finproxy-runner-1.0.0.jar app.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar app.jar extract

FROM openjdk:11.0.8-jre-slim
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder application/application/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/spring-boot-loader ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","/app/lib/external/*:/app/lib/internal/*:/application","org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

This worked fine, but when i increased replicas to 2. Both applications did not come up and caused this weird error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at com.finacle.finproxy.FinProxyApplication.main(FinProxyApplication.java:13)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

I tried different ways of debugging and I could login to both instances and could see files to be available but the application failed to read them.

I copied this lib folder to minikube and tried to bring up the application and it came up without any issues.

Can someone help me with the reason why this issue might be occurring?

Comment: Did you check the files permissions?

Comment: yes. it was 744

Comment: What vm-driver are you using?

Comment: hyperkit driver

Comment: Try using VirtualBox

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: no having the same issue even with virtualbox 6.10